# Is the address used to deploy contracts in JS tests in truffle always accounts[0]

Tags: truffle, testrpc, mocha

I've noticed that the deploying address in my truffle .js tests is equal to the address at accounts[0].

Since it's important to me to test the ownership of a contract, I'd like to know if it's guaranteed that contacts deployed by accounts[0] in the test suite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the case. `accounts[0]` is the default. If you like to test calling a function from another account, you can pass `{from: accounts[1]}` as the last parameter of your function. If you would have a function like this:

```js
MyContract.getBalance(address);
```

It would look like this:

```js
MyContract.getBalance.call(address, {from: accounts[1]});
```

You can get your accounts in truffle console with:

```js
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! The answer would be even better if you'd change to MyContract.getBalance.call(address);